# Kaa Changing sampling period

Tags: middleware, iot, platform, kaa

I was trying the kaa tutorial "Your first kaa application" and in the step "Change sampling period",
[the highlighted output is supposed to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKkJc.png)

But it does not, despite the other values still appear.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information like what SDK you use etc.?

Comment: Yes, about the SDK, I used **C**. In summary I used the sandbox and I've made the same things that the tutorial "Your first kaa application" asked to do.

Comment: Could you try the Data Collection demo application based on C SDK? It was the base for 'Your first Kaa application' code and matching the same logic. Thus, should it work well, you will be able to check what is the difference between them and try localizing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Press Active not just save
or is there ant more